# How to catch fault data returned by the webservice?

Tags: c#, wsdl, soa, fault

I have a wsdl which I am serializing. It is converted to c# but some object are not there.

```
<xsd:element name="StandardMessageFault">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="standard" type="p1:ExchangeFaultData"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Now I don't see this anywhere in code. I have searched and it says that SAP will return fault in case of failure so you sSo far I have found how to catch

```
catch(FaultException ex)
{
    FaultException FaultException = (FaultException)ex;
        MessageFault msgFault = FaultException.CreateMessageFault();
        XmlElement elm = msgFault.GetDetail < XmlElement > ();
}
```

I suspect that it would not work because it will look for fault data.

Comment: What does this have to do with the tool [tag:soapui]?

Comment: @SiKing: care to answer the question please.

Comment: I could possibly help you with SoapUI. I have never used SAP. Sorry.